# Which action to call function that uses Woocommerce conditionals, in plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a plugin that changes a few things at various places in Woocommerce templates and pages.

In that plugin I have an init() function that is called on the plugins_loaded action.

```
function start_plugin() {
    $plugin_content = new SRC\My_Plugin(
        // calls other classes etc here
    );
    $plugin_content->init();
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'start_plugin' );
```

The init() function calls my doo_woo() function which does all of the Woocommerce stuff, using conditions i.e. is_product() or is_cart().

```
public function init() {
        //option 1: uses woocommerce hook but conditionals don't work
        add_action( 'woocommerce_init', array( $this, 'doo_woo_related' )); // conditionals don't work.

        //option 2: uses unrelated hook but conditionals work
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'doo_woo' )); // conditionals work
    }
```

The question is around which hook I am using to call the doo_woo() function to get the conditionals to work. I guessed woocommerce_init would be right but that doesn't work. wp_enqueue_scripts is obviously nothing to do with what I'm trying to do but it works. I am guessing that this is based on the order in which the hooks are called.

Instead of wp_enqueue_scripts is there a more appropriate hook to use, one that comes after plugins_loaded?

Answer (score 1):

although in

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'doo_woo' ));
```

woocommerce conditionals tags work, i think the most appropriate hook to use is

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'doo_woo' ));
```

Comment: I think you might be right with that one. I had used

```
add_action('get_header', array( $this, 'doo_woo' ));
```

because this happened before wp_enqueue_scripts, which I need to call later. Reading the documentation template_redirect seems to be a bit of a better fit but still somewhat arbitrary for which one I go with.